# Ubuntu says my disk is full when installing updates but is not

Tags: software-installation, disk-usage

I'm trying to install updates on an Ubuntu Server but it keeps telling me that there is no space, here is my df -h output:

```
root@ServerMonitor:/# df -h
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
udev             486M   4,0K  486M   1% /dev
tmpfs            100M   504K   99M   1% /run
/dev/sda1         23G    17G  5,0G  77% /
none             4,0K      0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             5,0M      0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none             497M      0  497M   0% /run/shm
none             100M      0  100M   0% /run/user
```

What should I do?

Thanks

EDIT:

The output for df -i shows100% for /, how do I solve it?

```
root@ServerMonitor:/# df -i
S.ficheros     Nodos-i NUsados NLibres NUso% Montado en
udev            124415     421  123994    1% /dev
tmpfs           127221     373  126848    1% /run
/dev/sda1      1507328 1503606    3722  100% /
none            127221       2  127219    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            127221       4  127217    1% /run/lock
none            127221       1  127220    1% /run/shm
none            127221       2  127219    1% /run/user
```

Comment: Can you include the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: Also, can you include the output of `df -i` - just to make sure you haven't run out of inodes.

Comment: When you've run out of inodes, you simply have too many files on your drive. A normal running system does not have 1,5 million files. So you must have some clue as to why you have that many files on your disk. Start there.

Comment: Thanks to vidarlo and artur-meinild, that was the problem and the solution.